# Visual Studio Code won't let me type the letter s, how can I fix this? Uninstall and Reinstall didn't fix the problem. Any advice?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code won't let me type the letter s, how can I fix this? Uninstall and Reinstall didn't fix the problem. Has anyone else experienced this bizarre problem?

Comment: Can you type outside VSCode? Do you see any message in the bottom bar of VSCode?

Comment: yes, i can type s in other programs like chrome browser. in vscode, i did see s, s is not a command, but now.

Comment: @SteveByun I'm not sure this will help much but apparently, I found out that other programmers have had the same issue of not being able to type certain letters in VS Code. From what I understand this is a *big* bug in the editor. Many people have been complaining about it. You might wanna send a bug report to Microsoft. Apparently people reported this bug in 2017, 2019 and 2020 but nothing has been done

Comment: Btw may I ask which version of vscode you are using?

Comment: you might wanna check the docs on how crash reports work. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions